# iText / List : How to remove symbol from list?

Tags: java, list, pdf, itext

I have to create a PDF using iText (JAVA), and I have to include a List in a Cell.
I succeed to do this, but each element of my list contains the "-" symbol, and I would like to remove it.

I searched it but can't find an answer ... Could you help me please?

My code :

```
PdfPCell myCell = new PdfPCell();
com.itextpdf.text.List myList = new com.itextpdf.text.List();
myList.add(new ListItem("some text"));
myCell.addElement(myList);
```

Thanks for your answers ... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer by Jordi Castilla is correct: if you don't want a list, don't use a list.

If you *do* want a list, you can replace the list symbol by something else. See for instance the [RemoveListSymbol](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/RemoveListSymbol) example. In this example, I change the list symbol into `""`:

```
List list = new List();          
list.setListSymbol("");
list.add(new ListItem("Item 1"));
list.add(new ListItem("Item 2"));
list.add(new ListItem("Item 3"));
```

If you check [the resulting PDF](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/remove_listsymbol.pdf), you won't see the default list symbol `"-"` anymore.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the setListSymbol, but AFTER the list.add() lines .... genius ..
And yes, in my specific case, I prefere use a list than "\n"
Thank you again ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to make a list don't use it. Simply add new `Paragraphs` to the cell with "\n" or add a single `Paragraph` to the Cell and add Chunks to it, maybe not the most beautiful solution but it will work:

```
PdfPCell myCell = new PdfPCell();
myCell.addElement(new Paragraph("some text\n"));
```

or

```
PdfPCell myCell = new PdfPCell();
com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph myList = new com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph();
myList.add(new Chunk("some text\n"));
myCell.addElement(myList);
```

Comment: Yeah, either this is a good answer, or you and I don't understand the question. I'll post an alternative answer, but I must say that it's a strange question.

Comment: I don't think it's a strange question. Like in HTML, you may need to use a list (because it's more simple and the code is easier to read / debug).
Your solution is correct, but for the good reading of the code, I prefer use a list. But thank you anyway for your answer ;)